# Compiler optimization on not used function parameters

Tags: c++, optimization, rpc

I had a weird problem for a couple days using Windows RPC. Now I found the solution but I want to know what is the right way to prevent this problem.

So basically I had a problem calling [`NdrClientCall2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/rpcndr/nf-rpcndr-ndrclientcall2) function. As you can see in the docs, this function's third parameter is a pointer to the client-side calling stack. I changed the `midl.exe` generated C code to my own C++ version so my caller look like this:

```
void CppRpc::InternalCommand(int pSize, char buffer[1000000]) const
{
    RpcTryExcept
    {
        NdrClientCall2(PMIDL_STUB_DESC(&m_rpc_stup_description),
            PFORMAT_STRING(&MIDL_PROCFORMAT_STRING.Format[0]),
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&pSize));
    }
    RpcExcept(1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Runtime reported exception " << RpcExceptionCode()
            << std::endl;
    }
    RpcEndExcept
}
```

In release mode using full optimization I got access violation for a day or two, then I understood that since parameter `buffer` is not used in this function compiler optimization will remove this parameter somehow.

However I need this parameter to be on stack so the `NdrClientCall2` can stream it to the server. If I add any use for `buffer` for example `char dummy = buffer[0];` to the function buddy then it will work fine.

So my question here is, how to prevent optimization on this case?
I'm using visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not recommend doing this. Because since `InternalCommand` is your internal function, the compiler may change the layout of its parameters. Whereas (as I understand) you need specific layout where there's an `int` variable followed by the buffer reserved for the stack.

Not also that this layout may change if you change your function calling conventions (i.e. `cdecl` vs `stdcall`).

I would define a structure (POD) with a single `int` field, pass a pointer to it to your function, whereas the actual structure allocated by the caller has larger size.

Something like this:

```
struct StackFrame
{
    int pSize;
    char pStack[1000000]; // stack goes here
};

// ...

void CppRpc::InternalCommand(StackFrame* pStack) const
{
    RpcTryExcept
    {
        NdrClientCall2(PMIDL_STUB_DESC(&m_rpc_stup_description),
            PFORMAT_STRING(&MIDL_PROCFORMAT_STRING.Format[0]),
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(pStack));
    }
    RpcExcept(1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Runtime reported exception " << RpcExceptionCode()
            << std::endl;
    }
    RpcEndExcept
}
```

Comment: This is especially true since not all processors pass parameters on the stack in the first place, and even if stack-based, may not be passed right-to-left. Taking the address of `pSize` doesn't mean that `buffer` comes directly after.

Comment: I know it's been a while but I just wanted to inform you that your approach despite being the most reasonable one, didn't work for me (I really don't know why, It throws exception on assembly level, it should be something with windows RPC). Anyway I checked MIDL auto-generated C code again and I noticed that it used `#pragma optimize("", off)` on it's client side to disable compiler optimization on this file (this must be something unsolvable that made them do this). I did so then it works fine as expected. I'm leaving this comment for anyone stuck on this exact situation.